# How to use Impala to read Hive view containing complex types?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, impala

I have some data that is processed and model based on `case class`es, and the classes can also have other `case class`es in them, so the final table has complex data, `struct`, `array`. Using the case class I save the data in hive using `dataframe.saveAsTextFile(path)`.

This data sometimes changes or needs to have a different model, so for each iteration I use a suffix in the table name (some_data_v01, some_data_v03, etc.).

I also have queries that are run on a schedule on these tables, using Impala, so in order to not modify the query each time I save a a new table, I wanted to use a view that is always updated whenever I change the model.

The problem with that is I can't use Impala to create the `view`, because of the complex nature of the data in the tables (nested complex types). Apart from being a lot of work to expand the complex types, I want these types to be preserved (lots of level of nesting, duplication of data when joining arrays).

One solution was to create the view using Hive, like this

```
create view some_data as select * from some_data_v01;
```

But if I do this, when I want to use the table from Impala,

```
select * from some_data;
```

or even something simple, like

```
select some_value_not_nested, struct_type.some_int, struct_type.some_other_int from some_data;
```

the error is the following:

> AnalysisException: Expr 'some_data_v01.struct_type' in select list returns a complex type 
>   'STRUCT< some_int:INT, some_other_int:INT, nested_struct:STRUCT< nested_int:INT, nested_other_int:INT>, last_int:INT>'. Only scalar types are allowed in the select list.

Is there any way to access this view, or create it in some other way for it to work?

Comment: I would recommend add the create table statement and Ideally some test sample data. The issue is essentially because the sintax is different between hive and impala

Comment: Have you checked the file formats supported by Impala for complex types? https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_complex_types.html#complex_types_file_formats

Comment: Hello. Yes, the files are parquet, so no problem there. Also, the original table can be read from both Hive and Impala, only the hive created view cannot be read from impala.